# Understanding geohash and its associated rectangles

Tags: latitude-longitude, geohash

If I decode geohash `sj8101b0858n85202hbh0j` I get rectangle defined by min latitude, min longitude, max latitude, max longitude.

My understanding is that if I decode first part of any hash (e.g. `sj8101` in above example), I'll always get larger rectangle than what I had got with full hash. In other words, all the rectangles got by any hash (e.g. `sj8101???????`) will always be inside of the large rectangle that we get by shorter length hash (e.g. `sj8101`). Please can someone verify if my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. A geohash rectangle of precision *N* characters will always be fully contained by the corresponding geohash of size *N - 1* containing all the same preceding characters.